# I want to query the Google Big Query Dataset from PHP script

Tags: google-bigquery

I have downloaded the google-api-php-client for accessing the google api.
my code is

```
include_once "templates/base.php";
echo pageHeader("Simple API Access");
set_include_path("../src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Bigquery.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("my application name");
$apiKey = "--------my api key----";
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);
define("PROJECT_ID", my project ID);
define("DATASET_ID", "my data set ID");
$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
$results = $service->tables->listTables(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID);
print_r($results);
```

if i run the above file it givet the error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectID/datasets/datasetname/tables?key=API key: (401) Login Required' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client-master (2)\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Http\REST.php:80 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client-master (2)\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Http\REST.php(44): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client-master (2)\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Client.php(499): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client-master (2)\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\Resource.php(195): Google_Client->execute(Object(Google_Http_Request)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client-master (2)\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Service\B in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\google-api-php-client-master (2)\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Http\REST.php on line 80

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to troubleshoot/get error response when you run invalid BigQuery jobs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150608/how-to-troubleshoot-get-error-response-when-you-run-invalid-bigquery-jobs)

Comment: I am running the file on my localhost with XAMPP server installed ,above error saying Login Required what does this mean?

Comment: it means you forget to auth your application using OAUTH2.0 see the linked example

Comment: I authenticated my app by setting the required parameters but getting the error : Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in OAuth2.php:327 , OAuth2.php(289): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)

Comment: Thanks for help problem with Oath2.0 solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authentiate your app using OAUTH2.0

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");

if (isset($_SESSION['service_token'])) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['service_token']);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name, array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        ), $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$_SESSION['service_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
var_dump($_SESSION);
$bq = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
```

Comment: by trying this i am getting the error - Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in OAuth2.php:327 , OAuth2.php(289): Google_Auth_OAuth2->refreshTokenRequest(Array)

Comment: facing same problem Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }'' in OAuth2.php:327 plz help anyone

Comment: What's the point of he developer key if you still have to use OAuth?